# pci compliance and temporary files

Tags: encryption, pci-dss, credit-card

Does storing temporarily a non-encrypted file containing some PANs violate pci requirements? (for example because it is being processed by an application, or to open it on a file editor)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a violation of [PCI-DSS Requirements](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf), specifically requirement 3.4:

> Render PAN unreadable anywhere it is stored (including on portable digital media, backup media, and in logs) by using any of the following approaches:
>
> - One-way hashes based on strong cryptography (hash must be of the entire PAN)
> - Truncation (hashing cannot be used to replace the truncated segment of PAN)
> - Index tokens and pads (pads must be securely stored)
> - Strong cryptography with associated key-management processes and procedures

Comment: Is it considered "storing" loading PANs into RAM on systems in which the RAM might at some point temporarily be written on a pagefile?

Comment: I would say yes - it seems to be a gray area, but many would regard this as a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't write out unencrypted PAN.  If someone could force a crash while that file is being worked on, it would leave it sitting around on the server for anyone to access and the file could potentially be read by other processes.

There is no such thing as a "temporary" file.  There are only permanent files you intend to get rid of soon.

Also, why do you need to open it in a file editor to begin with?  That sounds like it is asking for a whole set of PCI problems all by itself.

Comment: For example if something goes wrong with a file being processed due to some bug and a developer has to inspect it. This makes me think the only solution is to encrypt the disk in this case. But which software to use and how to manage the keys(windows encryption is not compliant,right?)

Comment: Is it considered "storing" loading PANs into RAM on systems in which the RAM might at some point temporarily be written on a pagefile?

Comment: @mic.sca - good question.  I think technically it probably wouldn't be, but I'm not sure that a lot of people consider that risk.  It is at least slightly harder to access in a virtual memory file since it is more buried than if it is in a temp file, but technically it could still be compromised by dumping the virtual memory file.